# Beautiful soup for web scraping returns none

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, web-crawler

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#Finds the imdb rating of a given movie or TV series
search_term1="What is the imdb rating of "
search_term2=input("Enter the name of the movie or TV Series : ")
search_term=search_term1+search_term2
response=requests.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+search_term)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html5lib')
match=soup.find('div.slp.f')
#i tried 'div',_class="slp.f"
print(match) #this line is returning none
```

i am trying to extract imdb ratings of a movie from google search engine. Everytime it is returning none, although id is correct.

Comment: It's because you script leads you to a captcha page. Try to check using `print(response.url)`. I guess the returned url and the requested url are not the same.

Comment: Moreover, your search term should properly be encoded and I don't see any such attempt in your script. If your requested url is not already redirected try using `quote_plus(search_term)` and before that `from urllib.parse import quote_plus`.

Answer (score 1):

If you try to find `before-appbar` in the DOM:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
#Finds the imdb rating of a given movie or TV series
search_term1="What is the imdb rating of "
search_term2=input("Enter the name of the movie or TV Series : ")
search_term=search_term1+search_term2
response=requests.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+search_term)
print("before-appbar" in response.text)
```

The output is **False**

So clearly "before-appbar" is not an Id of any element here.

My guess is you are trying to determine the DOM element by inspecting it from the browser. However in most cases the DOM is changed a lot by JS so it will not match with what you get by using `requests` in python.

I can suggest you two possible solutions:

1. Save the response in an html file, open it in the browser, and then
   check which element you need to find.

   ```
   f = open("response.html", "w")
   f.write(response.text)
   f.close()
   ```
2. Use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and a headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies upon the way you are trying to search the id instead of

`print(soup.find(id="before-appbar"))`
with `print(soup.find({"id":"before-appbar"}))`

hope this solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're treating `find()` as [`select()` method that accepts `CSS` selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). `find()` method do **not** accept `CSS` selectors syntax.

```py
find('div.slp.f')    # No
find('div', 'slp f') # will work with find(). Syntax: ('tag', 'class') or ('tag', class_='class')
select('div.slp.f')  # Yes
```

Try to use `lxml` instead of `html5lib` because [`html5lib` is the slowest](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser). Also, there's no need in `selenium` nor saving the response in the file as [Bishakh Ghosh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50928518/15164646) mentioned for such task.

Make sure you're using [`user-agent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/User_agent) if not using `selenium` otherwise Google will block request eventually since the default `user-agent` in `requests` library is [`python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and Google understands that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and will block a request.

---

Since you haven't mentioned from what part of the page you were trying to scrape data (*organic results, knowledge graph, or answer box*) I don't bother finding the right element that will appear on each search result so the rating will always be there.

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

params = {
  "q": "imdb rating of infinity war",
  "hl": "en"
}

html = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search", headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

# scrapes from the snippet organic result
rating = soup.select_one('g-review-stars+ span').text
print(rating)

# Rating: 8.4/10
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is to iterate over structured JSON string and get the data you want, rather than figuring out why certain things don't work or extract as they should.

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "what is imdb rating of infinity war",
  "gl": "us",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

rating = results['organic_results'][0]['rich_snippet']['top']['detected_extensions']['rating']
print(rating)

# 8.4
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.

Answer (score 0):

You may get None because more variables needs to be passed in the request, not only the URL, but also minimum "Accept-Language" and "User-Agent" as headers. You can check your own data on this website http://myhttpheader.com/. So save the data as a dictionary in headers and after the URL just pass headers={"Accept-Language": "data_you_see", "User-Agent": "data_you_see"} and you should be ready to scrape

Comment: How does your *comment* essentially stand out from the existing answers that already show solutions and have you tested your suggestion or is it just an assumption?